# What is the fastest way to multiply snowdrops?

Tags: bulbs, propagation

I would like to multiply my snowdrops as fast as possible. I have about five plants right now. They normally double in size every year. Is there a faster way to do it? They are a little small for twin-scaling. What would the best method be? Would different conditions make them multiply faster? The bulbs are a bit small to propagate the way I do daffodils, but are a similar shape.

**Edit:** The plants now have green grape like fruits. Is it practical to save seeds, and if so, how?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grape like fruits are the seed pods.  Yes, you can grow snowdrops from seed, but for most bulbs it will take 2-4 years from seed to bulb.  Given how many seeds each one can produce this is easily your fastest way.

Failing that, however, pruning off the seed pods/ flowers ASAP means that the plant pushes more energy into growing the bulb.

Now, some basic math:

Suppose that you want 5000 snowdrops, and you have 5 right now.  Suppose that you give them lots of TLC and they double in number every year.  You will have 5 the first year, 10 the next, then 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120.

As far as I can tell snowdrops thrive in the same conditions that lawns do.  You can probably do a bit better than that.

Ten years.  But notice that it took you the first 5 to get to 100.  Go out and buy a hundred snowdrops and cut the time in half.  They are cheap.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree totally

1st snowdrops are expensive like hell!
then, they multiply times 5 every year under optimal conditions. which are rich soil and full sun.
Yes elewesii needs  full sunlight, but is less vegetative than nivalis so it's a tossup. By and large elwesii is more showy, more compact, the leaves are more vigorous.
I propagate them best in exposed lawns on sunny slopes.
Every fall I add a layer of compost and rake it so the grass grows through it. I do this three times each fall. Although backbreaking. after several years your lawn there is twice as lush and green as your neighbors. There is no need to water it and the clumps of nivalis are huge.

I dig them up whenever they show, March 21 to Memorial day if they haven't bloomed or not. Easiest is after they finished blooming, just pull out the clumps, return several bulbs into the hole and separate the bulbils.

Then water them and go plant them with a crowbar. I can do 1000 an hour that way but young and strong help is a welcome addition....

We forget that nivalis contains galantamine, an ACE inhibitor alkaloid,  toxic to most insects and moles. You will notice that your crocus and tulips planted amidst nivalis  don't get eaten by squirrels and molehills have totally disappeared!

It's the equivalent of Malathion, an all purpose garden insecticide.

Try spreading nivalis densely  under a nut tree and you will find that hull maggots are gone! Takes a few years though.....